# Cascading DropDownList in Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown, dropdownlistfor

I get this error in my PartialView when I run my project "An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Unknown Module. 
but was not handled in user code
Additional information: System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem contains no definition for value"

I have two tables category and Product in my databse, using EntityFramework ADO.ENTITY and the project is ASP.NET MVC
In Product table I have ProductId, ProductName and CategoryId
I want to create Cascading from Category DropDownList to Product DropDownList , I mean I want first to chose Category and then all product with the same CategoryId.
But does not working as it is, and please Help me.

This is my Controller:

```
public class CasController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Cas
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Db db = new Db();
            ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(GetCategoryList(), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
            return View();
        }

        public List<Category> GetCategoryList()
        {

            Db db = new Db();

            List<Category> categories = db.Category.ToList();

            return categories;


        }

        public ActionResult GetProductList(int catId)
        {

            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                List<Product> prList = db.Product.Where(x => x.CatId == catId).ToList();
                ViewBag.ProductOPtions = new SelectList(prList, "ProductId", "ProductName");
                return PartialView("DisplayProduct");
            }

        }
    }
```

And this is my Cascadingclass

```
public class CasCadingClass
{
   public int CatId { get; set; }
   public int PrId { get; set; }
}
```

This is Index view

```
@model Market.Models.CasCadingClass
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@if (ViewBag.Categories != null)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CatId, ViewBag.Categories as SelectList, "---Select Category---", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PrId, new SelectList(""), "--Select Product--", new { @class = "form-control" })

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#CatId").change(function () {

            var catId = $(this).val();
            debugger
            $.ajax({

                type: "Post",
                url: "/Cas/GetProductList?catId=" + catId,
                contentType: "html",
                success: function (response) {
                     debugger
                    $("#PrId").empty();
                    $("#PrId").append(response);

                }

            })

        })

    });


</script>
```

// Here in PartielView goes  error

```
@model Market.Product

<option value="">--- select Product---</option>
@if (ViewBag.ProductOPtions != null)
{

    foreach (var item in ViewBag.ProductOPtions)
    {
        <option value="@item.value">@item.Text</option>
    }

}
```

Comment: `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem contains no definition for value` ... [indeed it doesn't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#properties). But it does have a a property called `Value`. In C#/Razor, property names are case-sensitive.

Comment: @ADyson , O.M.G .. I struggled in hours .... Thank you very much!